# php_curl not able to run https (Google+ API)

Tags: php, ssl, curl, google-plus

I'm trying to pull the share count from Google+ using the code below:

```
function get_gplus_shares($url){
    $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc");
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
      $curl_results = curl_exec ($curl);
      curl_close ($curl);
      $json = json_decode($curl_results, true);
      return intval( $json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'] );
}
```

It is working fine on my local test environment, but not working on my live environment. I've installed `php_curl` using `sudo apt-get install curl` and `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`, which is working fine. Also added the `cacert.pem` by `sudo wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -O /usr/lib/ssl/certs/cacert.pem`. But doesn't seem to work. I really don't know where to proceed with this.

**Error Messages** - from apache error log.

`RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)` - but this error seems to fixed after adding `cacert.pem`.

`PHP Notice:  Undefined index: result` - PHP error, as the result of the function is empty.

`[ssl:error] [pid 20743] AH02032: Hostname **IP-ADDRESS** provided via SNI and hostname **mydomain.com** provided via HTTP are different` - just saw this error, not sure if related.

Comment: Post all error messages, please

Comment: please see edits @AxelAmthor.

Comment: FYI, that's a private Google API that could change or break at anytime without notice.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check by adding below two options

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "pathto/cacert.pem");
```

Comment: still not running, `Undefined index: result` error.

Answer (score 1):

Check if below works:

```
<?PHP

// connect via SSL, but don't check cert
$handle=curl_init('https://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$content = curl_exec($handle);

echo $c
?>
```

Comment: the output is: `302 Moved
The document has moved here.` Where here is `https://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=iZtEVfaaNYPW8gewnoCoBw`

Comment: you have to change the URL of your own, for this use "https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=LpxEVbm3FsGq8wfXqIHgDw" instead of "https://www.google.com"

Comment: dear you have to add your options and post parameter that is given in the your post, and also change the URL

Comment: got it buddy! the problem was with the url, I was passing encoded url. Guess that was the problem. thanks for your help!